# Tile-based game

Tags: перевод

How to translate "tile-based game" into Russian correctly?

Comment: Please add some context and/or describe the meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean [tile-based video games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_video_game), the word tile here has no russian counterpart, so it is usually translated as `игры с тайловой графикой` or `тайловые игры`. If you mean just [tile-based games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_game), then it can be translated like:

- Настольные игры с использованием игральных костей.
- Настольные игры с игральными костями.

In order to reduce tautology these often reduced to `игры с костями` (sounds pretty ominous out of context, doesn't it) or even `игры в кости`.

Also, as Quassnoi had mentioned, кости in russian stands for both dice and tile games.

For example,

> Игра "1000 на кубиках" относится к одной из самых азартных и увлекательных *игр в кости*. Везение помноженное на мастерство и точный расчет - вот главное условие выигрыша, как, кстати, и в большинстве игр подобного рода.

is about [dice game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_10000).

It is worth to mention that in some games there is a tendency to call tiles just `тайлы`. For example, in [official rules](http://www.mahjong.ru/files/mjru0909.pdf) of Mahjong in Russian, you will find only "кости". But de-facto it is common to  many russian players [to use](http://bit.ly/Ot4M2J) "тайлы".

For mor popular tile-based games it is not the case. You'll probably never hear "домино с тайлами из слоновой кости" :)

Yet, there is derivative form of кости, `костяшки`, which are more likely to be associated with tiles.

Comment: I believe *игральная кость* would mean "die", while "tile" (domino piece) would be *костяшка*.

Comment: @Quassnoi, don't know English good enough, to be honest. But here is a quote from Wikipedia -  Domino tiles are usually rectangular, twice as long as they are wide and at least twice as wide as they are thick, though games exist with square tiles, triangular tiles and even hexagonal tiles. So it's tile. On the other hand, there is an expression - погреметь костями, which actually means - play domino.

Comment: my point was that *игральная кость* (without further clarification) would mean both "die" and "tile", the first meaning being much more prevalent. *Костяшка*, on the other hand, would unequivocally mean "tile". The game *1000 на кубиках*, btw, is a dice game.

Comment: Valid point, @Quassnoi.

Comment: @Quassnoi, edited the answer. If you want, feel free to create your own answer based on your remarks. I will edit mine in order to intersect less as possible. I will be great to up vote yours )

Answer (score 2):

I think English `tile-based game` means board games with tiles, like Carcassonne or Forgotten Island. This case `tile` is a piece of land or map, so nearest Russian equivalent should be `Настрольная игра`, there are no specific word for tile. usually it's called same `тайл` or `участок`.