# How to talk about rolling dice

Tags: перевод

Both Katzner's English-Russian and Oxford English-Russian dictionary translate dice as:

> игральние кости -- dice
>
> играть в кости -- to play dice

But neither of them actually include the phrase "to roll dice." The answer by shabunc in [this](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/906/tile-based-game/907#907) Russian stackexchange question includes a quote talking about a dice game, but it also doesn't have any verbs talking about dice rolling.

#### Google Translate

I'm not having luck finding articles about how to talk about games in russian, but plugging different phrasings of `rolling the dice` into Google translate comes up with the following:

> roll the dice --> бросить кости
>
> to roll dice --> бросить кубики
>
> he rolled the dice --> он закатил кости
>
> he rolled a 7 on the dice --> он закатил семь на кости

Looking back at the dictionaries for what `закатить` means, Katzner says (and Oxford is pretty similar):

> закатывать / закатить -- to roll; wheel (into, under, behind, etc.)

Neither gives rolling dice as an example.

#### Questions

- (given how flaky google translate sometimes is) Is google translate correct about how you talk about rolling dice? As in -- can you use either закатить or бросить?
- Can кости be used interchangeably with кубики?
- If google's wrong, how do you phrase it? What verbs do you use?
- How do you talk about the results of a die roll / what number you rolled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dice - "игральные кости"`, they may also be called `"кубики"`, `rolling the dice` - `"Бросить кубики"` in context, the player must roll the dice.

> Ответ 
>   1. «Кидать кости», «Бросать кубики».

2. Да.
3. the result is voiced each digit separately «Шесть - Пять», «Один-Один»

Comment: Answer
1. "Кидать кости", "Бросать кубики".
2. yes.
3. the result is voiced each digit separately "Шесть - Пять", "Один-Один"

Comment: @Heagon nice distinction, I forgot about that. So then, how would you specify: d4 vs d6 vs d8 etc...?

Comment: @xgord from what I've encountered personally, you would either call it by a proper geometric name, as in "икосаэдр" (icosahedron), "тетраэдр" (tetrahedron); or by a more colloquial name, like "двадцатигранник" (literally "twenty-sided") or "пирамидка" (pyramid).

Comment: Though d4 or d20 definitely aren't cubes, many people would refer to them as "кубики" not for their shape, but for their use (you roll it and you get a number). Those who care more about geometry, call them dx (d4, d10) pronounced as `дэ четыре`, `дэ десять` etc.

Comment: @Alissa and Heagon thanks for the explanations! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

"Закатил кости" sounds strange. )

> Он бросил кости. Выпало 7.

A less frequent variant might be

> Он выбросил 7 на костях.

Comment: 7? What kind of dice is that? ))

Comment: with 2 dice its 1 + 6

Comment: @Sergey Slepov the very dice the author of the question meant.

Comment: @SergeySlepov there are plenty of games out there that use dice with more than 6-sides -- or even some with fewer than 6 :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would talk about rolling a dice to my son:

- Чья очередь кидать кубик? Твоя? Давай, кидай! Сколько у тебя выпало? Пять? А у меня шесть!

To me "играть в кости" sounds old, something a Treasure Island pirate might do.

Definitely not "закатить кости"... unless we are talking about a pirate rolling a wheelbarrow full of bones!

Comment: кубики i suppose is apt when they're used to determine the number of moves of a chip, but кости is a game in its own right, which isn't meant for children